# Insert into SQLite database with limit

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I need some help with my code. I want to write the data into the database on per row for per channel with limit data.

When I try this:

```
#store the id and width of buttons in a database
for button_id, prog_width in zip(program_id, program_width):
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO buttons(button_ids, button_width)" + " VALUES(?, ?)", [button_id, prog_width])[/code]
```

It will insert the data in each row in one channel. I want to insert the data in each row for per channel. I have 7 channels in a database.

I have 10 data for `button_id` and `program_width` for per channel so the total data for `button_id` (10 data for per channel) and `program_width` 10 data for per channel) is 70. There are 120 data for per channel that I have stored in a database. What the code will do is they will insert the first 70 rows in one channel to insert the 70 data which is wrong. I want the code to insert the 10 data of `button_id` for per channel, then insert the next 10 data for the next channel and so on.

I have already tried this:

```
cur5.execute("INSERT INTO buttons(button_ids, button_width) LIMIT 10" + " VALUES(?, ?)", [button_id, prog_width])
```

It will give me an error: **OperationalError: near "LIMIT": syntax error**

Can you please show me an example how I could insert the data in each row for per channel with a limit of 10?

Comment: In your buttons table in SQLite, where is the channel field for 7 types? Right now, it seems you intend to update the same data to all channels.

Comment: @Parfait what do you mean by where is the channel field for 7 types? yes but I am trying to insert the 10 elements in the database before get pass to the next channel. How I could do that? can you post the code?

Comment: *I want to insert the data in each row for per channel.* ...how do you determine channel? Shouldn't the append query be: `INSERT INTO buttons(channel, button_ids, button_width)...`?

Comment: Well I am using to store the list of channels in a list so do you know how I could use the insert into buttons with a match of a title to allow me to store the button in the line row as the tile before it would pass the elements and go to the next channel?

Comment: How does this *channels* list relate to *program_id* and *program_width* lists? Is the corresponding channel for example the last 4 characters in each element of *program_id*? Is this *title* = *program_id*? I do want to help you but the main issue I have is how does channel info connect to the data you are trying to import? Remember databases are relational (i.e., tables relate). Please edit your post with such list data to illustrate.